# Keeping rows with a minimum number of observations per group

Tags: r, row, subset

With the following data, I would like to remove all the rows either containing less than or equal to only 1, 1s or 2s. The date set contains either 1 or 2.

```
mydata
      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
    1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2
    2  2  2  2  1  2  2  2
    3  1  1  1  1  2  2  2
    4  2  1  2  1  2  2  1
    5  2  1  1  1  1  1  1
    6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
    7  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Remove row #2,5,6 & 7 because

```
sum(mydata[2,]=="1") #2nd row contains only one 1.
sum(mydata[5,]=="2") #5th row contains only one 2.
sum(mydata[6,]=="2") #6th row contains only no 2.
sum(mydata[7,]=="1") #7th row contains only no 1
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d[rowSums(d == 1) > 1 & rowSums(d == 2) > 1,]
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
#1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2
#3  1  1  1  1  2  2  2
#4  2  1  2  1  2  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to loop through the rows get the `table` and check if the frequency of all the elements are greater than 1 (just in case there are more number of unique elements per row)

```
mydata[apply(mydata, 1, function(x) all(table(factor(x, levels = 1:2)) >1)),]
#. X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
#1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2
#3  1  1  1  1  2  2  2
#4  2  1  2  1  2  2  1
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), X2 = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), X3 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
    X4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), X5 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L), X6 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), X7 = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```